# Не могу разобраться с ошибкой CS0201

Tags: c#

Нашёл в интернете `генератор паролей`, решил его доработать, но оказалось что он был сделан ещё в далеком 2010-ом году, когда была другая версия языка.

Вот код программы:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PasswordCreatorByZekoyka
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string dic = "";
            string tmp = "";
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                char nchar;
                for (int i = 65; i < 91; i)
                {
                    nchar = (char)i;
                    tmp = Convert.ToString(nchar);
                }
                dic = tmp;
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked) dic = "0123456789";
            if (checkBox3.Checked) dic = textBox2.Text;
            if (checkBox4.Checked)
            {
                tmp = "";
                char nchar;
                for (int i = 97; i < 123; i)
                {
                    nchar = (char)i;
                    tmp = Convert.ToString(nchar);
                }
                dic = tmp;
            }
            string pass = "";
            Random mran = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i)
            {
                int index = Convert.ToUInt16(mran.NextDouble() * dic.Length) % dic.Length;
                char ScharS = dic[index];
                pass = Convert.ToString(ScharS);
            }
            textBox1.Text = pass;
        }
    }
}
```

Но возникает ошибка, с корнем которой я не могу разобраться.

`Ошибка CS0201 В качестве оператора могут использоваться только выражения назначения, вызова, инкремента, декремента и создания нового объекта.`

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Все версии C# обратно совместимы. Просто код криво скопирован, или вставлен. То есть конструкция, которую вы показали, не будет работать ни в одной версии языка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во всех циклах необходимо прописать операцию инкремента для итератора

вместо

```
for (int i = 65; i < 91; i)
```

надо

```
for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое =).